# Not a consistent error code returned from MIP SDK for C++

Tags: c++, microsoft-information-protection, mip-sdk

I am using C++ MIP sdk (version 1.8) to apply MIP tags on data files from my JAVA application using JNI (because java MIP sdk does not have support for RHEL). But right now I am testing on Windows only.

When I am applying classification label for unsupported file types like .txt or .pst or .png file formats. Except for .png I always get error code "mipns::ErrorType::NOT_SUPPORTED_OPERATION" but for .png files I am getting error code "mipns::ErrorType::INTERNAL_ERROR".
As I want to show these stats to the end user where I am differentiating the errors due to unsupported file types for mip classification vs any other processing errors.

Can someone please confirm if this is some error within MIP sdk or am I doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You are working with file types that have different capabilities.

TXT files do not support classification via metadata, so it is correct to obtain "mipns::ErrorType::NOT_SUPPORTED_OPERATION" error code, and SDK are working as expected.

PNG files, instead, support classification via metadata, and applying classification labels via SDK should work straightforwardly.
(see documentation on other supported/unsupoorted file types here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/rms-client/clientv2-admin-guide-file-types#file-types-supported-for-classification-only).

To investigate the "mipns::ErrorType::INTERNAL_ERROR", my suggestion is to check MIP SDK logs that are created under the path passed in mip::MipConfiguration constructor.